# Visual Studio 2010 RTM started giving me 'does not exist in the current context errors'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Just installed the trial version of Visual Studio 2010 RTM.

Now I keep getting :

The name 'NoPanel' does not exist in the current context

Errors (where no panel is just about any control in the .aspx file)
also I got several errors trying to deploy pages and it would not send the .cs file over ...or pdfs in the Content directory (even though I had copy always set)...

This is happening on a pair of  mixed ASP.NET MVC and Webforms sites.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 has now been officially released and is available. Have you tried using the production version?

Comment: Isn't RTM the production ready? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_to_manufacture#RTM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the file and click Convert to web application.

Answer (score 1):

RTM is the official release ... and it seems to have something to do with the change with CodeFile and CodeBehind.   Also with the .NET 4 there is apparently additional namespace checking as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a problem with name not found in context. Upgraded project from vs 2008 to vs 2010. Application would build and run find. However, debugging would not stop at break points and errors on the pages said control name could not be found in current context. To fix the problem I:

1. In the aspx files changed CodeBehind to CodeFile
2. Changed the Inherits reference to remove all qualifiers leaving only the form name (ie. xxx.xxx.WebForm7 to WebForm7)
3. Removed namespace statement from the aspx.cs file.

Error messages went away and debugging started working again.